# Display error from a form in the same page

Tags: php, forms

I have a form

```
<form method="GET" action="/boxr_app/v2/profile">
        <input type="text" name="gamertag" placeholder="What is your gamertag?" autocomplete="off" size="50" />
        <input type="submit" value="Search" />
    </form>
```

And I want to check if the input is less than 4, it display an error in the same page, just below the form, but I cant figure how to do that, any idea?
I've tried this

```
<?php if($_GET['gamertag] < 4) { echo 'invalid blah blah blah'; } ?>
```

Comment: less than 4, as in 1, 2 or 3, or less than 4 as in `abc` but not `abcde` ?

Comment: sorry, less than 4 characters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `action` parameter to make sure you submit to the same page. Then add this under your form

```
<?php if( $_GET['gamertag'] < 4) { echo 'invalid blah blah blah'; } ?>
```

Where i added a quote (') after gamertag. Are you validating the length of the input? Then you should use `strlen($_GET['gamertag'])`.

Comment: Works, but what if I need to use the action parameter?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you are trying to do?

```
if(strlen($_GET['gamertag']<4)) { echo 'invalid blah blah blah'; }
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php